# How to write file in node.js after connecting with Java application via child process

Tags: javascript, java, xml, node.js, xslt

I am newbie to node.js. I have created a child process in node.js to connect it with my Java program. I used eclipse to create an executable jar file(Saxon.jar). This is my app.js(JavaScript) file.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java -jar Saxon.jar',
  function (error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if(error !== null){
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});

module.exports = child;
```

My Java program is converting xml into html webpage using xslt stylesheet. Right now, I am getting my result in command prompt. The result looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yTIY.png

I want my output to write in a HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) to write `stdout` to the file then:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pathToFile = 'path/to/file.html';

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java -jar Saxon.jar', function (error, stdout, stderr){
    fs.writeFile(pathToFile, stdout, function(err) {
       if(err) console.error(err);
    })
});

module.exports = child;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I am getting my output as html web page.